# Meta API using Python - How to request instagram feed publications with paid boost

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

So I basically have code in Python that makes requests to my clients' pages collecting information such as the publication's url, reach, impressions, likes and comments.

Request to feed publications:

```
import requests
url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{page_id}/media?fields=caption%2Cpermalink%2Cthumbnail_url%2Ctimestamp%2Cig_id%2Ccomments_count%2Clike_count%2Cinsights.metric(plays,impressions,reach,total_interactions,comments,likes,saved,shares,profile_visits,follows).period(lifetime)%2Cid&limit=101&access_token={TOKEN}&since={since}&until={until}"
r = requests.get(url)
```

However, I noticed that some of these posts were boosted by paid media. And although I already have requests from ad accounts too, I can't link the organic post (published in the feed) and indicate how many of the impressions/reach/likes/comments came from this paid boost.

Media Request:

```
url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{ad_account}/insights?level=ad&fields=date_start%2Cdate_stop%2Caccount_name%2Ccampaign_name%2Ccampaign_id%2Cadset_name%2Cadset_id%2Cad_name%2Cad_id%2Cobjective%2Cspend%2Creach%2Cimpressions%2Cclicks%2Cinline_post_engagement&breakdowns=publisher_platform&date_preset=last_7d&limit=700&time_increment=1&access_token={TOKEN}"
r = requests.get(url)
```

Has anyone gone through the same situation? I looked in the [Meta documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview) but I still haven't been able to make the paid + organic results match the value I see in the tool.